# awk script for copy/paste part of string

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

Problem:
I have several config files (ProgramName.conf) that need to be edited with awk or sed. The first line contains several letters in place after ":" and end with "]" ***ProgramName***. Or copy filename (it's same as ProgramName). I need to copy ***ProgramName*** to the 4th between "command=docker-compose run --rm --name" and "artisan". After conteiner name always word "artisan" in place.

**Upd**
Thanks for answers, problem solved!

input:

```
[program:ProgramName]
process_name=
directory=
command=docker-compose run --rm --name artisan some text
```

target output:

```
[program:ProgramName]
process_name=
directory=
command=docker-compose run --rm --name ProgramName artisan some text
```

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: All the solution/answer are fine, it gives the desired result with your given input, now you change the requirement/input again...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
gawk -i inplace '
    BEGIN { RS = ORS = ""; FS = OFS = "\n" }
    match($1, /^\[program:(.*)\]/, a) {
        for (i = 2; i <= NF; ++i)
            if ($i ~ /^command=docker-compose run --rm --name/)
                $i = "command=docker-compose run --rm --name " a[1]
    }
    { print $0 RT }' file
```

Study the GNU Awk manual for details.

Answer (score 0):

If `ed` is available/acceptable, something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

ed -s file.txt <<-'EOF'
  /^\[program:.*\]$/t/^command=/
  s/^\[.*:\(.*\)\]$/ \1/
  -;+j
  ,p
  Q
EOF
```

---

In one-line

```
printf '%s\n' '/^\[program:.*\]$/t/^command=/' 's/^\[.*:\(.*\)\]$/ \1/' '-;+j' ,p Q |  ed -s file.txt
```

---

- Change `Q` to `w` if *in-place* editing is required.
- Remove the `,p` to silence the output.

Answer (score -1):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be then

```
[program:ProgramName]
process_name=
directory=
command=docker-compose run --rm --name
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="]|:|\\["}/^\[program:/{name=$3;n=NR}NR==n+3{$0=$0 " " name}{print}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
[program:ProgramName]
process_name=
directory=
command=docker-compose run --rm --name ProgramName
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that field separator (`FS`) is `]` or `:` or `[` then for line starting with `[program:` I store third column value as `name` and number of row (`NR`) as `n`, then for line which is three lines after thtat happen i.e. number row equals n plus three I append space and name to line and set that as line value, for every line I `print` it. Be warned that it does modify

> to the third line

to comply with your requirement, therefore make sure it is right place do change for all your cases.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*